# Easiest way to determine which file is included in C?

Tags: c, include, header-files

For instance, in

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

what's the easiest way to figure out the path to the included file?

Edit: I'm using gcc 9.2.0 on Arch Linux.

Comment: The answer depends on your operating system and compiler. Please update your question include this information.

Answer (score 3):

I do usually generate dependencies in my `Makefile` with the following command line:

```
gcc main.c -o main -MD
```

The `-MD` flag generates a dependency file, where all included headers are listed.

Comment: This also speeds up subsequent compilations, so you're killing two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find where gcc is searching for the include files.

Try

```
echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -
```

on my computer (Ubuntu on windows 10) it shows

```
piotr@DESKTOP-6R1GELF:~$ echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
```

Comment: Do you actually use Windows for anything? If not my first choice would be to remove it and run Debian. Of course, it's your computer.

Comment: Windows 10 - I personally do not complain. I use also linux machine but now with real linux-es on windows it 100% meets my requirements. I could not configure the linux machine to work reliably with 4x 4k monitors.

Comment: Ah. Configuration with Linux is tricky in that way and Windows 10 just works out of the box. If you cared you could set up `xrandr` properly but since your setup works I imagine you don't. I've had bad experiences with Windows before (and I'm a free software geek) so I don't use it.